# Adding some logic in v-for with v-if Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I have some json with below results

```
{
  "module": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Module 1",
      "type": "URL",
      "size": 1,
      "image": "https://localhost/image1.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Module 2",
      "type": "YOUTUBE",
      "size": 2,
      "image": "https://localhost/image2.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i want to render it on a page with some loop and conditional, like below

```
<template>
  <section class="page-section homescreen mt-4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3" v-bind:key="data.index" v-for="data in modules" v-if="data.size == 1">
              <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" v-bind:key="data.index" v-for="data in modules" v-if="data.size == 2">
              <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      modules: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Module 1",
          "type": "URL",
          "size": 1,
          "image": "https://localhost/image1.png"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Module 2",
          "type": "YOUTUBE",
          "size": 2,
          "image": "https://localhost/image2.png"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

But instead of success, i got some error saying

> 5:99  error  The 'modules' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be
> replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead.
> You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'  vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for
> 8:99  error  The 'modules' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be
> replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead.
> You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'  vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for

Actually i want to create the `<div class="col-lg-3">` part to be dynamic based on the json, if `size:1` mean to have `col-lg-3` and if `size:2` mean to have `col-lg-6`

Any explanation and suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`eslint-plugin-vue`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-use-v-if-with-v-for.html) was telling you to do this:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3" v-bind:key="data.index" v-for="data in modules.filter(o=>o.size == 1)">
    <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6" v-bind:key="data.index" v-for="data in modules.filter(o=>o.size == 2)">
    <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
</div>
```

In your case, it can be simplified as

```html
<div :class="'col-lg-'+data.size*3" v-bind:key="data.index" v-for="data in modules">
    <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
</div>
```

Comment: THAT is scalable ! Nice job mate ;)

Answer (score 2):

### In case you have just two sizes:

You can use [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to achieve this requirement.

First, create two new computed properties like:

```
computed: {
  modulesSize1: function() {
    return this.modules.filter(x => x.size == 1)
  },
  modulesSize2: function() {
    return this.modules.filter(x => x.size == 2)
  }
}
```

Now, you can easily loop through computed properties `modulesSize1` && `modulesSize2` like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3" v-bind:key="data.index" v-for="data in modulesSize1" >
    <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" v-bind:key="data.index" v-for="data in modulesSize2" >
    <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### In case you have multiple sizes:

First, create a simple method like:

```
methods: {
  getClass: function(size) {
    return `col-lg-${size * 3}`
  },
}
```

and then we can update template and use [Class Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) like:

```
<div :class="getClass(data.size)" :key="data.index" v-for="data in modules">
  <img class="img-fluid" :src="`${data.image}`" :alt="`${data.title}`" />
</div>
```

Comment: IMO it's not really scalable, imagine if in a near future he'll have twenty different pictures size ? Will he copy that snippet twenty times ?

Answer (score 2):

If it's essentially something with css classes, why don't you use `v-bind:class` or `:class` with your condition ?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

But like said in the error message you'll certainly have to create a sub component and then use props on it

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 1):

The `v-if` is essentially baked in to the `v-for` (if `modules` is empty nothing will render) so it's recommended not to use them in combination. If you need it for a separate condition, like you do here, then you'll have to move your `v-for` on to the `<img>` itself.

You also won't be able to use `data.size` this way so you'd have to use something like `v-if="modules[0].size == 1"` etc.

**Edit**

@Palash answer is probably the more efficient way to solve this.

**Edit 2**

@r0ulito and @xianshenglu also makes a really good point, if it's just a class issue, use v-bind.

Comment: its not in the image, but in the div, but i will try it anyway.. UPDATE:not possible, can you help me some snippet?

Comment: I updated my answer as I missed that you won't be able to use `data.size` this way

Comment: If you could include the data from your axios request i'll make a snippet